# chrome.local.storage save directory info and retrieve this information

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, filereader

Is it possible to save information from a directory with chrome.local.storage and subsequently retrieve this information to display the files contained inside.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, sorry. Tell your use case step by step (and which of the steps you already know how to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a google-chrome-app tag on your question, I assume you're asking about Chrome Apps and not Chrome Extensions, so here's my answer:

There is no chrome.local.storage API for Chrome Apps. There is a chrome.storage API, but you can't do anything with directories or files, as the storage model is key-value pairs.

True, those key-value pairs have a physical representation in a file (or files), but those are hidden from apps, and very difficult to find even by a human.

You can access actual files and directories with the chrome.fileSystem APIs, which are completely different.